Is there any way to constrain the max value of an integer?
Is there any way to ensure that value can never exceed 32 or a particular number?
I have a struct:
#[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct ABC<AccountId> {
    pub owner_id: AccountId,
    pub current_total: u64
}

I want to set maximum value of current_total as 32. I can add validation in extrinsic but I am looking for more cleaner and better way.

I think this is more of a Rust question than Substrate. take a look at this answer for example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673674/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-data-type-that-only-accepts-a-range-of-values

Depending on where you want to use it, you can implement a custom decoder that rejects anything > 32.
This would work when you want to use it as argument for an extrinsic, since the runtime has to decode everything before the call can execute.
Currently you are deriving Decode, but its easily possible to implement it yourself:
impl<AccountId: Decode> Decode for ABC<AccountId> {
    fn decode<I: codec::Input>(value: &mut I) -> Result<Self, codec::Error> {
        let owner_id = AccountId::decode(value)?;
        let current_total = u64::decode(value)?;

        if current_total > 32 {
            Err(codec::Error::from("current_total is too large"))
        } else {
            Ok(ABC { owner_id, current_total })
        }
    }
}

Only downside of this is that the front-end will not know about. The front-end will assume that this is a normal u32, but AFAIK there are some scale-info derive macros to give it custom metadata annotations.
